# An olympiad number theory problem asking for prime numbers with a certain property

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Let $\displaystyle T_k=\sum^{k}_{j=1} \frac{1}{j2^j}$, where $k$ is a positive integer. Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\frac{T_k}{k+1}\equiv 0 \pmod{p},$$ where $\frac{a}{b} \pmod{p}$ means $ab^{-1} \pmod{p}$ and $b^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b \pmod{p}$.

This is an olympiad  problem asked by my previous teacher in my high school. It is so hard to me that the only thing I can do is to check whether the desired property holds for small numbers.

Comment: @dezdichado No known formula exists for $T_k$

Comment: @祝浩然 check my answer

Comment: I think there is a need for clarification here, whether we are dividing in the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ or inatead in the field $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, for every odd prime $p$ there is a positive integer $k$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^{-i}$ is $0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Obviously there is no such $k$ for this to be true in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. We are clearly dividing in $\mathbb{F}_p$ or the solution to the problem is easy. There is clearly no way, if division were in $\mathbb{Q}$, that the sum in question could ever be large enough to be a positive multiple of $p$.

Comment: @jjagmath ahh, I must have confused it with the sum of $j2^j$ my bad.

Comment: Seems to hold for all $3<p<10000$.

Comment: I wonder if replacing $2$ with another number works.

Comment: Seems like $2$ is the lucky number: Almost none of the primes less than $10000$ divide the sum, where $2$ is replaced with a greater integer less than $20$.

Comment: I've dropped down an answer, trying to respect the olympic spirit, and also to find the related structure, so that similar properties may pop up. I like the problem, +1, and would like to insert it in some booklet on CAS (computer algebra systems) - e.g. sage, www.sagemath.org - so any further information on the problem would help me to give credits and time / space coordinates for it. Do you know any details about the origin of the problem?! (Country, level/age, national or international olympiad, author, year...) Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't no the origin.This is a training problem for the students preparing for CMO(a math olympaid exam for Chinese high school students).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Introduction:** Let $p$ be a prime number,
$$p\ge 5\ ,$$
fixed from now on. We consider the sum
$$
\begin{aligned}
S
&=
S(p)
=
\sum_{1\le k\le p-2}\frac{T_k}{k+1}
=
\sum_{1\le j\le k\le p-2}\frac1{j(k+1)\; 2^j}
\\
&=
\sum_{0< j< n<p}\frac1{jn\; 2^j}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This is a rational number, $S\in\Bbb Q$. In sums appearing below, i will try to use indices $j,n\in\Bbb Z$ most times satisfying $0<j<n<p$.

We will **show** that the **numerator of $S$ is divisible by** $p$. In its denominator there appear only factors between $1$ and $(p-1)$. So we can and do equivalently work in the field $\Bbb F=\Bbb F_p$ with $p$ elements with the same expression, thus consider from now on $S\in \Bbb F_p$,
and **show** $S=0$ in $\Bbb F_p$.

*Note:* The field $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p$ is known at olympiad level, it is in some countries denoted by $\Bbb Z_p$ since ever in the manuals, because $p$-adic integers are most times useless. If not completely useless, people using them should find a better notation.

*Warming-up:*
The index set of the sum $S$ accepts a bijective map, $(j,n)\to(j',n'):=(p-n,p-j)$. Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
S &=
\sum_{0< j< n<p}\frac1{jn\; 2^j}
=
\sum_{0< j< n<p}\frac{2^{p-j}}{2(p-j)(p-n)}
=
\sum_{0< j'< n'<p}\frac{2^{n'}}{2n'j'}
\\
&=
\frac 12\sum_{0< j< n<p}\frac{2^n}{jn}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

**First solution:** This solution is not the olympiad solution, but it is the  structural one, in a particular sense, let call it K-theoretical in nature. It "explains" also in a simple manner why the **two** appearing in the formula is the special guest. I am citing an article of a friend, written in collaboration:

[Finite polylogarithms, their multiple analogues
and the Shannon entropy,
Philippe Elbaz-Vincent and Herbert Gangl](https://maths.dur.ac.uk/users/herbert.gangl/Entropy_and_Polyanalogs_finalV1.pdf)

Let us introduce the polynomials in $\Bbb F_p[x,y]$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L_{11}(x,y) &= \sum_{0<j<n<p}\frac{x^jy^n}{jn}\ ,\\
L_1(x) &=\sum_{0<j<p}\frac{x^j}{j}\ ,\\
L_2(x) &=\sum_{0<j<p}\frac{x^j}{j^2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now i am citing results from §3.1:

> **Theorem 2:** Theorem 2. The finite $(1, 1)$-logarithm $L_{11}(x, y)$ can be expressed in terms of $L_2$. More precisely, we have:
> $$
> \tag{$\dagger$}
> yL_{11}\left(x,\frac 1y\right)
> =
> L_2\left(
> -y^p    \color{blue}{\left[\frac xy\right]}
> -(1-y)^p\color{blue}{\left[\frac {1-x}{1-y}\right]}
> +\color{blue}{[1-x]}
> +\color{blue}{[1-y]}
> \right)
> \ .
> $$
> The proof of this result takes
> $\displaystyle(1 − y)^pL_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-y}\right)$
> and decomposes the (triangular)
> domain over which the summation variables run into an "open" part (a triangle) and three "boundary" parts (one diagonal, a vertical and a horizontal line) and identifies the former with the $L_{11}$-expression and the latter with the three remaining terms in the equation. At a crucial step one uses the binomial identity
> $$
> \sum_{0\le r\le N}
> \binom{N-r}s
> \binom rt
> =
> \binom{N+1}{s+t+1}\ .
> $$
> I have to say some words about the symbolic character of applying $L_2$ on a symbolic linear combination, as in the relation $\dagger$. The blue right parentheses are "symbols", we apply $L_2$ on them, obtaining elements in $\Bbb F_p$. These elements are then inserted formally in the linear combination.

**Corollary:** The sum $S$ in our question satisfies
$\displaystyle S=\sum_{0<j<n<p}\frac1{jn\;2^j}=L_{11}\left(\frac 12,1\right)=0$.

**Proof:** We set $y=1$ in the polynomial identity $\dagger$.
There is some problem with the denominator $(1-y)$ of the second symbol.
But note that the corresponding term is multiplied with $(1-y)^p$, so the contribution is zero. (The polynomial identity is valid at infinitely many values in $\bar{\Bbb F}_p$.) We obtain
$$
\tag{$\dagger_{y=1}$}
L_{11}(x,1)
=
L_2\left(
-1^p  \color{blue}{\left[\frac x1\right]}
+\color{blue}{[1-x]}
+\color{blue}{[0]}
\right)
=-L_2(x)+L_2(1-x)
\ .
$$
So which is the value of $x$ delivering a trivial vanishing?!

$\square$

**Note:**
The values $x=0,1, \frac 12$
are "trivial" solutions of $L_2(x)=L_2(1-x)$.
For many primes $p$ these are also the only solutions in
$\Bbb F_p$. The first two are useless for our setting, we cannot use them to get "similar problems".
Up to $90$ the exceptions are $29,37,41,43,53,61$.

**Proof of $\dagger$ in Theorem 2 for $y=1$.** We show the **polynomial** identity
$L_{11}(x,1)+L_2(x) = L_2(1-x)$. The involved two polynomials have degree $\le (p-1)$. To show such an equality, here and in similar cases, we check one point, usually $x=0$, and take the derivative. Sometime we multiply with a non-zero polynomial, obtaining an equivalent identity.
To start, note $L_{11}(0,1)=L_2(0)$, and
$$
L_2(1) = \sum_{0<j<p}\frac 1{j^2}=\sum_{0<j<p}j^2
=\frac 16(p-1)p(2p-1)=0\ .
$$
This was typed in order to show what goes wrong for $p=3$.
(When $L_2(1)=1+1=2\ne0$.)

Now we work using successive equivalences from step to step, using the mark $(!)$
for an equality to be shown:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L_{11}(x,1)+L_2(x) 
&\overset{(!)}=
L_2(1-x)
\\
\sum_{0<j\le n<p}\frac 1{jn}\cdot x^j
&\overset{(!)}=
\sum_{0<n<p}\frac 1{n^2}\cdot(1-x)^n
\\
&\qquad\text{Equality in $x=0$, take derivative times $(1-x)$}
\\
\sum_{0<j\le n<p}\frac 1{n}\cdot (x^{j-1}-x^j)
&\overset{(!)}=
-\sum_{0<n<p}\frac 1n\cdot(1-x)^n
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Fix a degree $k$. Let us compare
the above two polynomials in degree $k$. For $k=0$, which is special, we take on the L.H.S. of the last line $j=1$, in the sum, so the L.H.S. free coefficient is $\sum(1/n)=\sum n=0$. The same zero sum, times $(-1)$, is obtained as the R.H.S. free coefficient.
In degree $k=(p-1)$ we compare

- $-1/n=-1/(p-1)=1$ for the relevant term for $j=n=p-1$ on the L.H.S. with
- $-1/n=-1/(p-1)=1$ for the relevant term for $n=p-1$ on the R.H.S.

The other, generic values of $k$. We obtain on the L.H.S. telescopic cancellations. The part in $x^k$ that matches $x^j$, so $j=k$, is
$\displaystyle -\sum_{k\le n<p}\frac 1n$.
The part in $x^k$ that matches $x^{j-1}$, so $j-1=k$, $j=k+1$, is
$\displaystyle +\sum_{k+1\le n<p}\frac 1n$.
So the L.H.S. has the coefficient in $x^k$ equal to
$$
-\frac 1k\ .
$$
Which is the corresponding term on the R.H.S. - we compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text{Coefficient of $x^k$ in }-\sum_{0<n<p}\frac 1n\cdot(1-x)^n
\\
&\qquad =-\sum_{k\le n<p}\frac 1n\cdot\binom nk(-1)^k
=-\frac{(-1)^k}k\sum_{k\le n<p}\binom {n-1}{k-1}
%\\
%=-\frac{(-1)^k}k\left(\ 
%\binom{k-1}{k-1} +
%\binom{k-1}{k-1} + \dots
%\binom{k-1}{(p-1)-1} \ 
%\right)
%\\
%&\qquad 
=-\frac{(-1)^k}k\binom{p-1}{k}
\\
&\qquad=-\frac{(-1)^k}k\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-1-k)!}
\\
&\qquad=-\frac 1k\frac{(p-1)!}
{(\color{gray}{p}-1)
 (\color{gray}{p}-2)\dots
 (\color{gray}{p}-k)(p-1-k)!} =-\frac 1k
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

**Second solution:**
This is a solution based on harmonic number identities, it can be extracted from

[Arithmetic Theory of Harmonic Numbers,
Zhi-Wei Sun](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-02/S0002-9939-2011-10925-0/S0002-9939-2011-10925-0.pdf)

as follows. The result we want is *Theorem 1* from *loc. cit.*, relation $(1.1)$, which is explicitly:
$$
\tag{$1.1$}
\sum_{0<k<p}\frac {H_k}{k2^k}=0\qquad\text{ modulo } p\ .
$$
Here, $H_k$ is the $k$.th harmonic number, a rational number, considered in $\Bbb F_p$, well, in fact rather in the ring of $p$-adic numbers. The proof is given in *loc. cit.* in §3, page 422, and it is a computation modulo $p^2$ based on combinatorial relations involving harmonic numbers.

Note that our sum is
$$
S=
\sum_{0<j<n<p}\frac 1{jn\; 2^j}
=
\sum_{0<j<p}\frac 1{j\; 2^j}\sum_{j<n<p}\frac 1n
\ ,
$$
and the last inner sum in $n$ is not exactly the harmonic number $H_j$,
but related to this one since the sum over $1/n$ for $0<n<p$ is zero,
$n\to 1/n$ being a bijection of $\Bbb F_p^\times$.

---

**Third solution:** This is an ad-hoc solution, based on

How can we transform the sum $S$ using "other symmetries" of its expression. Well, the index set of all $(j,n)$ is rigid, we did with it all we could. So let us use algebraic manipulations of the terms in $S$. We use the splitting:
$$
\tag{$*$}
\frac 1{jn}=\frac 1{n-j}\left(\frac 1j-\frac 1n\right)\ .
$$
It is also useful to introduce the harmonic numbers $H_k\in\Bbb F_p$, defined for $0<k<p$ in the usual manner,
$$
H_k=\frac 11+\frac 12+\dots+\frac 1k\in\Bbb F_p\ .
$$
Note that $H_{p-1}=0$, since the sum of the inverses of non-zero elements in
$\Bbb F_p$ is the same as the sum of its non-zero elements. As a corollary,
$$
H_k-H_{p-(k+1)}
=
\left(
\frac 11+\dots+\frac 1k
\right)
+\left(
\frac1{\color{gray}{p}-(\color{gray}{p}-(k+1))} +\dots +
\frac1{\color{gray}{p}-1}
\right)
=0\ .
$$
We record now some identities.
$$
\begin{aligned}
S 
&
=\sum_{0<j<p-1}\frac 1{j2^j}\sum_{j<n<p}\frac 1n
=\sum_{0<j<p-1}\frac 1{j2^j}(\underbrace{H_{p-1}}_{=0}-H_j)
%=-\sum_{0<j<p-1}\frac 1{j2^j}H_j
\\
&=-\sum_{0<j<\color{red}p}\frac 1{j2^j}H_j
\ ,
\\[3mm]
S &=
\sum_{0< j< n<p}\frac1{jn\; 2^j}
\overset{(*)}=
\sum_{0< j< n<p}\frac1{n-j}\left(\frac 1{j2^j}-\frac 1{n2^j}\right)
\\
&=
\underbrace{\sum_{0<j<n<p}\frac 1{j(n-j)2^j}}_{=:U}
-
\underbrace{\sum_{0<j<n<p}\frac 1{n(n-j)2^j}}_{=:V}\ ,
\\[3mm]
U
&
=\sum_{0<j<p-1}\frac 1{j2^j}\sum_{j<n<p}\frac 1{n-j}
%=\sum_{0<j<p-1}\frac 1{j2^j}
\left(\frac 11+\frac 12+\dots+\frac1{p-1-j}\right)
=\sum_{0<j<p-1}\frac 1{j2^j}H_{p-(j+1)}
\\
&=\sum_{0<j<\color{red}p}\frac 1{j2^j}H_j =-S\ ,
\qquad\text{ thus so far we have }
\\
2S &=V\ ,
\\[3mm]
V
&
=\sum_{0<j<n<p}\frac 1{(n-j)n\;2^j}
=\sum_{0<j'<n<p}\frac 1{j'n\;2^{n-j'}}
=\sum_{0<j<n<p}\frac 1{jn}\;2^{p-n+j}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now one can show in general the polynomial identity, using ideas and notaions taken from the first proof:
$$
\sum_{0<j<n<p}\frac 1{jn}\;x^{p-n+j}
=
2L_2(1-x)\ .
$$
(We need it only for $x=2$, so even an argument for this particular case is enough.)
It leads to $2S=V=2L_2(-1)=0$.

$\square$

*Note:* This last proof was started first, unfortunately, i could not
complete it at an elementary level using *natural* ideas.

---

---

Sage code supporting computations:

We test that the given sum is zero for all primes $p$ up to $500$.

```
def check_prime(p):
    F = GF(p)
    S = sum([F(1) / F(j) / F(n) / F(2)^j for j in [1..p-2] for n in [j+1..p-1]])
    return S == 0

for p in primes(500):
    if not check_prime(p):
        print(f'FAILED for {p}')
print('JOB DONE.')
```

And we get:

```
FAILED for 3
JOB DONE.
```

It may be useful to compute also some other related objects.

```
p = 17
F = GF(p)
R.<X> = PolynomialRing(F) 

def L11(x, y):
    F = x.parent()
    p = F.characteristic()
    R = [(j, n) for j in [1..p-2] for n in [j+1..p-1]]
    return sum([F(1) / F(j) / F(n) * x^j * y^n for j, n in R])

def L1(x, F=None):
    if not F:    F = x.parent()
    return sum([1/j * x^j for j in F if j])

def L2(x, F=None):
    if not F:    F = x.parent()
    return sum([1/j^2 * x^j for j in F if j])

print('Let us check x^p L11(x, 1/x) = 2 L2(1 - x)\n')
print(f'X^p * L11(X, 1/X) is:\n{X^p * L11(X, 1/X)}\n')
print(f'      2 L2(1 - X) is:\n{2*L2(1 -X, F)}\n')
```

And we obtain:

```
Let us check x^p L11(x, 1/x) = 2 L2(1 - x)

X^p * L11(X, 1/X) is:
2*X^16 + 10*X^15 + 5*X^14 + 6*X^13 + 11*X^12 + 13*X^11 + 15*X^10
       + 2*X^9 + 6*X^8 + X^7 + 5*X^6 + 2*X^5 + 9*X^4 + 16*X^3 + 16*X^2

      2 L2(1 - X) is:
2*X^16 + 10*X^15 + 5*X^14 + 6*X^13 + 11*X^12 + 13*X^11 + 15*X^10
       + 2*X^9 + 6*X^8 + X^7 + 5*X^6 + 2*X^5 + 9*X^4 + 16*X^3 + 16*X^2
```

Result was manually adjusted, line break to fit in the given page width.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. Thank you!

Comment: nice answer. It also checks out that this is "hard" number theory problem in China and the proof of Theorem 1.1 cited in the paper pretty much looked like what I expected. I do remember deriving something very similar in high school in preparation for the IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_k(x)=\sum_{j=1}^k x^j/j.$ For $0<x<1$ we have $S_k(x)<\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x^j/j=-\ln (1-x).$ So $T_k=S_k(1/2)<-\ln (1-1/2)=\ln 2.$

So $$0<\sum_{k=1}^{p-2}T_k/(k+1)<(\ln 2)\sum_{k=1}^{p-2}1/(k+1)=(\ln 2)(-1+H(p-1))$$ where $H(p-1)=\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}(1/j)=\gamma+d_{p-1}+\ln (p-1)$

where $\gamma\approx 0.577$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $0<d_{p-1}<1/2(p-1).$ So is there any integer $p\ge 2$ such that $p<(\ln 2)(-1+\gamma+1/2(p-1)+\ln(p-1))$?

Comment: Well, well, well… it doesn’t look like a high school olympiad problem anymore, does it?

Comment: in a problem like this, divisions are typically understood via a modular arithmetic. So $\frac{1}{k+1}$ is not a fraction but the multiplicative inverse of $k+1\bmod p. $

Comment: @insipidintegrator. Well no it doesn't.  But at my age (70) I am unable to restrain myself to high-school methods. :) Maybe there is a very elementary solution.

Comment: @dezdichado. It may be that the Q is in $\Bbb Z_{/p}$ and not in $\Bbb R$ but if so, it should say so.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet check my answer. Not sure if there is a mistake in my solution but it is elementary

Comment: My limited mental capacity tells me that the partial sums of a series which converges to $\ln 2=0.693$ cannot be an integer anyways, so dividing by $k+1$ in the rational number sense, is just useless unless magic happens and $\displaystyle \sum \frac{T_k}{k+1}$ is proved to be an integer. It intuitively _feels_ like the division _has_ to be a multiplicative inverse (wrt congruences) type thing .

Comment: @eipim1. Your A is fine. ...............

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing some information in the question because in its current state, there are no possible solutions. The quantity in question is always less than $p$. Here's the reasoning:

Let $S_p = \sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\frac{T_k}{k+1}$ and let $p > 2$
$$T_k = \sum_{j=1}^k {\frac{1}{j2^j}} \leq \sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{2^j} < 1$$
$$\implies T_k < 1$$
$$\implies \frac{T_k}{k+1} < \frac{1}{k+1}$$
$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\frac{T_k}{k+1} < \sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\frac{1}{k+1}$$
$$\implies S_p < H_{p-1} - 1 < log_2{(p)} - 1$$
The last step comes from the upper bound of harmonic series. Hence $0<S_p < log_2(p) - 1 < p.$

Comment: As far as I know, in the context of high school olympiads, a fraction $\pmod{n}$ is considered as the product of the numerator and the multiplicative inverse of the denominator $\pmod{n}$. If $n$ is a prime number, talking about a fraction $\pmod{n}$ only makes sense if the denominator is not divisible by $n$. Hence, the problem is to find primes which divide the numerator of the given fraction.